# How to set a vertical axis title via Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I have the following code:

```
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var chart = sheet.newChart().asLineChart()
                             .setTitle("Hello World")
                             .setXAxisTitle("X Axis")
                             .setYAxisTitle("Y Axis")
                             .setNumHeaders(1)
                             .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
                             .setPosition(1, 7, 0, 0)
                             .setOption("width", 8 * 100)
                             .setOption("height", 15 * 21)
                             .addRange(sheet.getRange(2, 1, 13, 5))
                             .build();

 sheet.insertChart(chart);
```

I am trying to set a title for the Y-Axis, which works fine if I use the user interface, however when I attempt to do it programmatically it doesn't work. I tried using `setOption('vAxis.title', 'Y Axis')`, but that doesn't work either.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using **v** --> `vAxis`...

```
.setOption('vAxis.title', 'Y Axis')
```

another attempt would be...

```
.setOption('vAxes.0.title', 'Y Axis')
```

Comment: I did try that, only spelled it wrong in the question, sorry about that but it doesn't work.

Comment: cheers! that is the option to use when there is more than one y-axis, and 0 is the first...